# Using c# is math vector faster on the stack or the heap?

Tags: c#, heap-memory

My understanding is that the CPU does its math operations in conjunction with the CPU caches (L1 etc) and that if a value needed for an operation is not already in the cache a page will need to be got from RAM before the calculation can be performed. It seems reasonable to think, therefore, that managed heap RAM is a better place to be having your Vector data than than any old hole the OS managed to find somewhere in the great expanse of unmanaged stack RAM. I say this because I assume managed memory is held together tighter than unmanaged memory, and therefore there is more likelihood that vectors (x, y, z) for math operations will be stored in same pages loaded into the cache; whereas vectors as structs on the stack might be pages apart. Could anyone explain the pros and cons of class based rather than struct based vector classes in this light?

Comment: Seriously I think that the best thing for you to do is to implement both options and perform some diagnostic testing. Otherwise you're just doing an academic exercise with no practical application...

Comment: As far as I understand the stack is too big to fit inside the L1 cache and it is part of the OS job to get the required pages from RAM into the cache as need.

Comment: Enigmativity: If someone already knows the answer duplicating the work would be a waste of time. Furthermore the assumptions I am making may be wrong so it is worth positing the query. Lastly, the conclusion that follows from the assumptions and the logic is hardly academic... it is bears upon practically every vector math library that uses structs rather than classes to manage its data types.

Comment: @StephenJones - You need to use the "@" symbol before a user name to make sure that they get a notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPU cache is managed completely by CPU. Memory that is recently accessed is cached by relatively large chunks (i.e. 128 bytes around accessed position).

OSes manage paging to/from physical memory. If you application hitting that process often enough (i.e. size of your data is way bigger that physical RAM) than you have other issues to worry about outside CPU cache line hits and misses.

There is essentially no difference between stack and heap from that point of view. The only meaningful difference is how close the next piece of data to be used to one of recently used once.

In most cases math classes (vector/matrix/points) are stored in sequential blocks of memory for both managed and native implementations. So caching behavior is likely be comparable unless one explicitly does some strange allocations to make individual elements to be far apart in memory.

Summary: make sure to profile your code and keep data compact if performance is of huge concern.

Try and measure different iteration orders across arrays. I.e. if iteration crosses caching lines every time it could be slower - walk by row or by column first in 2d array could show measurable difference for large enough data sets when caches have to be repopulated on most array access...

Comment: .Thankyou for the reply. The problem I have in mind is loading data from a text file into a game engine. Initially the data enters RAM as a string (byte array). This gets converted into arrays of strings, which are further converted into arrays of floats. Most of the floats are sent through to the GPU and we do not need to keep hold of them, but some of them need to kept as collision objects. If the collision floats are held as vector structs on the stack won't these structs be located after the hole left by the preceding strings, string arrays, and GPU float arrays?...

Comment: ...After loading several objects, that may or may not fit in the previous holes, the collision data will be scattered throughout RAM and the OS will have trouble "chunking" the structs into the cache in a single "page". If the collision floats are held in vector classes, on the other hand, the holes will be removed every time the GC reorganizes the heap and the collision data will be compact in RAM. Or is it the case that "pages" into the cache are pointers to relevant data and their location in RAM irrelevant?

Comment: @StephenJones, I think you mixing concepts of VM pages and CPU cache lines - they are not related and having holes between object not necessary impact CPU caching (as lines are short enough)... And you need to read on memory allocation in CLR too - you can't keep array of structs in such a way that structs themselves allocated on the stack. Anyway - more reading and actual perf measurements is the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

The stack is faster [here](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/rickm/archive/2008/04/15/improving-performance-through-stack-allocation-net-memory-management-part-2.aspx) is a site that cover it in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am thinking "stack" has a dual meaning: function stack and RAM, consider: 
"Think of the Stack as a series of boxes stacked one on top of the next.  We keep track of what's going on in our application by stacking another box on top every time we call a method (called a Frame).  We can only use what's in the top box on the stack." http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx. How can we only use what is in the top box when we are using a struct that may be placed at the bottom?